# How to build a SVN project which depends on another SVN multi module project in Jenkins?

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins

My multi module project structure is:

```
Parent project - MyProj
  |
  |- ChildProj1
  |
  |- ChildProj2
```

Another project `TestProj` depends on `child1` and `child2`.

So, what should be the POM dependencies in `TestProj` POM file for Jenkins to detect and include the `child1` and `child2` SVN projects while building and executing the test cases using Jenkins? I have created two projects in Jenkins. `TestProj`'s build is triggered on build completion of `MyProj`. But, it doesn't seem to work. What should be the dependencies in `TestProj` POM? I have given the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>proj1</groupId>
        <artifactId>child1</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <systemPath>https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/child1/pom.xml</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>proj1</groupId>
        <artifactId>child2</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <systemPath>https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/child2/pom.xml</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies can only be made on `jar` files which are located locally. if you need systemPath you can use this but it should be prevented...If you need them as it looks like you should create multi module build.

```
+ (root) pom.xml (modules)
   !
   +-- child1 (pom.xml)
   !
   +-- child1 (pom.xml)
```

which is checked in one into SVN  where `root` is in the `trunk` of svn repository...

Comment: The project structure we have implemented is the multi module project contains all the basic functionalities that are being used by other projects which contain test cases that grow in size over time So, would it be possible to integrate such a project structure in Jenkins for build and test case execution without restructuring ?

Comment: For such build in Jenkins you only need a single job in Jenkins...which can ran all tests...